# How to identify Apple App Store Country in Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

How do we determine, in code (is there an api or some tricks for that?), which country's Apple App Store was used to download the app from?
Note that options such as NSLocale and asking user for access to location are **not** what I am looking for, but specifically which App Store was used to download. Or is it plain impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an API for this in iOS 13.

You can now get the country code from `SKStorefront`. The easiest way to access that value is like so:

`SKPaymentQueue.default().storefront?.countryCode`

Comment: Nice, but the singleton is `default()` not `shared`
On the other hand, it feels a bit weird to be calling `SKPaymentQueue` when your app doesn't have in-app purchases or even uses `SKPaymentQueue`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `NSLocale` is only option to find this. There is no such an API for which store.

But for one more step further.

`CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProvider.isoCountryCode`

can be use to double check. by the way %50 times `NSLocale` works

Comment: thanks, this doesn't answer my question, but the isoCountryCode is something I wasn't aware of, and will come in handy, so upvoting

Comment: thanks mate. I also learn iOS 13 storefront, that also helped me. cheers